# Не работает вспышка в android 6

Tags: java, android

```
Camera cam = Camera.Open();
Camera.Parameters p = cam.getParameters();
p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
cam.setParameters(p);
cam.startPreview();
```

Данный фрагмент кода работает на 4.4, но 6-м не работает в чем может быть проблема?